# Unbiased PN junction Diode

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, fermi-energy

I have certain doubts regarding the formation and movement of majority charge carriers when a p type and n type semiconductors are fused together.

1. When electrons and holes mover from p to n and n to p due to diffusion, the immobile ions stays there only. After a certain time  further movement of electron and holes do not occur and we say a space charge region is created.

My question is in many books they show immobile charge carrier as a depletion regions, and says they stop the further movement of electron and holes.

Also an electric field is created within the depletion region. Is this because of immobile ions or what.

2. Why there must be a constant Fermi level through out the specimen, i.e. Fermi level of p and n type are same. I don't get the logic behind that. Is it because for easy movement of electron and holes to move across i.e. why they must be same or what. If so then why we see a barrier after equilibrium even though Fermi level are same.

Edit-Please suggest some good books so that i can clear my doubts on the formation of PN junction and further for my course too.

Comment: Yes, the immobile charged dopant ions provide the charge that creates the field in the depletion region. The Fermi energy is closely analogous to the electron chemical potential (but not exactly!), so if the Fermi energy is not constant, the electrons are not in equilibrium.

Comment: What does that meas by saying electrons are not in equilibrium. And @JonCuster when you say electron, you mean electron in conduction band are not in equilibrium with conduction band of holes or what? I am totally confused by this.